# Understanding the scope values in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a question about the $scope values.

Example :

```
$scope.editItem = $scope.data.item;
```

So in `$scope.editItem` I have the same value as `$scope.data.item`.

But If I modify a value in `$scope.editItem`, the value is changing too in `$scope.data.item`.

I'm creating an edition form in a grid, and I'd like to edit items without changing the original value.

So if the user begin to edit the row, and cancel then I need to get back the original datas in my `$scope.editITem` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happening because you are assigning reference to `$scope.data.item`. So as the reference/address is same for both scope variables, it's updating whenever you are updating `$scope.editItem`. (two-way binding concept)

So, all you have to do is, assign a copy of `$scope.data.item` to `$scope.editItem`. Then your problem'll be fixed.

Do as follow:

```
$scope.editItem = angular.copy($scope.data.item)
```

For more please read, https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy

Answer (score 3):

This happens because you're assigning a reference to `$scope.data.item`, not copying the value.

In order to achieve what you want, you need to deep copy your object using

`$scope.editItem = angular.copy($scope.data.item)`

Answer (score 2):

As long as I understand you only want to copy the value from one variable into another instead of the reference. A dummy way I know to accomplish that is to use `angular.copy` ([doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)) so that you can get this

```
$scope.editItem = angular.copy($scope.data.item)
```